# Pandas ValueError : Index Data must be 1 dimensional

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file which looks like this :

```
V,ITEM_1,ITEM_2,ITEM_3,ITEM_4,ITEM_5,ITEM_6,ITEM_7,ITEM_8,ITEM_9,ITEM_10,ITEM_11
,1°C,2°C,3°C,4°C,5°C,6°C,7°C,8°C,9°C,10°C,11°C
100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
101,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
102,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Im reading the csv file using pandas (v 1.3.2)

```
import pandas as pd

csv_input = pd.read_csv(filename, header= [0, 1], na_filter=True)
print(csv_input)
```

Output:

```
                   V ITEM_1 ITEM_2 ITEM_3 ITEM_4 ITEM_5 ITEM_6 ITEM_7 ITEM_8 ITEM_9 ITEM_10 ITEM_11
  Unnamed: 0_level_1    1°C    2°C    3°C    4°C    5°C    6°C    7°C    8°C    9°C    10°C    11°C
0                100      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0
1                101      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0
2                102      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0
```

However when trying to use `set_index` on `V` using `csv_input.set_index('V', inplace=True)` i run into an error which I dont understand why im getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users//venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users//venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5501, in set_index
    index = ensure_index_from_sequences(arrays, names)
  File "/Users//venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 6275, in ensure_index_from_sequences
    return Index(sequences[0], name=names)
  File "/Users//venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 469, in __new__
    arr = klass._ensure_array(arr, dtype, copy)
  File "/Users//venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/numeric.py", line 171, in _ensure_array
    raise ValueError("Index data must be 1-dimensional")
ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional
```

When using a similar-ish data-set from the internet which looks like

```
First Name,Gender,Start Date,Last Login Time,Salary,Bonus %,Senior Management,Team
Douglas,Male,8/6/1993,12:42 PM,97308,6.945,true,Marketing
Thomas,Male,3/31/1996,6:53 AM,61933,4.17,true,
Maria,Female,4/23/1993,11:17 AM,130590,11.858,false,Finance
Jerry,Male,3/4/2005,1:00 PM,138705,9.34,true,Finance
```

I dont run into an errors...

Comment: What about adding `index_col` in param of `read_csv` ->  `pd.read_csv(filename, header= [0, 1],index_col=[0], na_filter=True)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have a MultiIndex as columns. You can't just set one of the levels as index and leave the other one to hang.

Either drop one level before setting index:

```
csv_input.droplevel(1, axis=1).set_index('V')
```

```
     ITEM_1  ITEM_2  ITEM_3  ITEM_4  ITEM_5  ITEM_6  ITEM_7  ITEM_8  ITEM_9  ITEM_10  ITEM_11
V                                                                                            
100       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0        0
101       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0        0
102       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0        0
```

Or set the whole column as index:

```
csv_input.set_index(('V', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1'))
```

```
                        ITEM_1 ITEM_2 ITEM_3 ITEM_4 ITEM_5 ITEM_6 ITEM_7 ITEM_8 ITEM_9 ITEM_10 ITEM_11
                           1°C    2°C    3°C    4°C    5°C    6°C    7°C    8°C    9°C    10°C    11°C
(V, Unnamed: 0_level_1)                                                                               
100                          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0
101                          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0
102                          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0
```

To get a clean "V" as index:

```
csv_input.set_index(('V', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1')).rename_axis('V')
```

```
    ITEM_1 ITEM_2 ITEM_3 ITEM_4 ITEM_5 ITEM_6 ITEM_7 ITEM_8 ITEM_9 ITEM_10 ITEM_11
       1°C    2°C    3°C    4°C    5°C    6°C    7°C    8°C    9°C    10°C    11°C
V                                                                                 
100      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0
101      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0
102      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0
```